# How to get time only with date and time in C#

Tags: c#, csv, datetime, time

I have .CSV file and there is Date column but it has content date and time like follows;

24/02/2017 13:57:53

manageInstance.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(valuesInCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

So,how I get time only from this format.I am doing C# programming.If anyone know,please help me.I am newer to this language.

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far

Comment: First, you use [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the date/time. Then to get the time only, [DateTime.TimeOfDay property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Google (or bing), find solutions, try them out and if any look promising, but don't quite work, post questions here with minimal viable source. It's that simple, StackOverflow is not about having others do the work for you.

Comment: @Jim Mischel  thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your `String` as `DateTime` like

```
var text = "24/02/2017 13:57:53";
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(text);
```

And then you can access the time like

```
var time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get time like `var timeOnly = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;`.

Comment: Hope Op's want the excel data which is stored as datetime format in c#